# select with detachedCriteria and order by sum of different column

Tags: hibernate, detachedcriteria

i have this simple MySQL query :

```
SELECT * from foo ORDER BY (col1+col2+col3) DESC;
```

the result of col1+col2+col3 is an Integer.

is there a way to make this with DetachedCriteria using hibernate for spring ?

P.S. i'm quite inexperienced with DetachedCriteria

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way using the formula annotation.  The annotation would be placed on the Foo class.  Note that the formula annotation accepts sql column names and not object property names.

```
@Formula("col1+col2+col3")
private int calculatedValue;

public int getCalculatedValue() {
    return calculatedValue;
}

public void setCalculatedValue(int calculatedValue) {
    this.calculatedValue = calculatedValue;
}
```

The detached query would look like something below.

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class);
query.addOrder(Order.desc("calculatedValue"));
List<Foo> results = query.getExecutableCriteria(session).setMaxResults(100).list();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what about the hibernate mapping file ? should i also map the formula there ? how ?
i tried your code and i'm getting a "property not found exception"...
the hibernate documentation about @Formula is lacking

Comment: SOLVED...i'm not using annotations in my project so i've just added the formula in the hibernate mapping file...thanks Manuel